# Mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_home

Tags: linux, centos, disk, fsck

When I mount my `/dev/VolGroup/lv_home` there get error:

```
[root@localhost VolGroup]# mount /dev/VolGroup/lv_home /home/
Mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_home,
       Missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       Dmesg | tail or so

[root@localhost VolGroup]# fsck -t ext4 /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_home
Fsck from util-linux-ng 2.17.2
E2fsck 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
Read block 114327552 (invalid parameter) Error ignore error <y>?

Mandatory coverage <y>? Yes

Write block 114327552 (invalid parameter) error. Ignore error <y>?

The superblock contains an invalid ext3 log (inode 8).
Clear <y>? Yes

*** ext3 journal has been deleted - filesystem is now ext2 only ***

Superblock has_log flag is clear, but a log inode is present.
Clear <y>? Yes

The file system size (according to the super block) is 228899840 block s
The physical size of the device is 26214400 block s
Either the super block or the partition table is likely to be corrupt!
Interrupt <y>? Yes

Write block 114327552 (invalid parameter) error. Ignore error <y>?

[root@localhost VolGroup]# mount /dev/VolGroup/lv_home /home/
Mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_home,
       Missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       Dmesg | tail or so
```

you see i tried`fsck -t ext4 /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_home` but still not work.

my system is CentOS 6.8.

---

**EDIT1**

```
[root@localhost local]# grep /home /etc/fstab
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_home /home                   ext4    defaults        1 0
```

**EDIT-02**

when I use the `dmesg | tail`, there get this error:

```
[root@localhost local]#  dmesg | tail
type=1305 audit(1548343606.632:3): audit_pid=3415 old=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 res=1
EXT4-fs (dm-2): bad geometry: block count 228899840 exceeds size of device (26214400 blocks)
usb 3-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
possible SYN flooding on port 22. Sending cookies.
possible SYN flooding on port 22. Sending cookies.
possible SYN flooding on port 22. Sending cookies.
possible SYN flooding on port 22. Sending cookies.
possible SYN flooding on port 22. Sending cookies.
EXT4-fs (dm-2): bad geometry: block count 228899840 exceeds size of device (26214400 blocks)
EXT4-fs (dm-2): bad geometry: block count 228899840 exceeds size of device (26214400 blocks)
```

---

**EDIT03**

```
[root@localhost local]# history 
    1  yum -y install screen
    2  screen -S lnmp
    3  cd /usr/local/nginx/conf/vhost/
    4  ll
    5  vi www.SDFS.com.conf 
    6  lsblk
    7  ls
    8  cd /home/
    9  ls
   10  cd /dev/VolGroup/
   11  ls
   12  cd lv_home 
   13  ls
   14  cd lv_root 
   15  df -h
   16  fdisl -l
   17  fdisk -l
   18  cat /etc/mtab 
   19  mount /dev/VolGroup/lv_home /home/
   20  fsck -t ext4 /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_home 
   21  mount /dev/VolGroup/lv_home /home/
   22  ls
   23  cd
   24  ls
   25  cd /
   26  ls
   27  cd usr/local/
   28  ls
   29  cd mysql/
   30  ls
   31  cd ..
   32  ls
   33  cd nginx/
   34  ls
   35  cd html/
   36  ls
   37  cd ..
   38  ls
   39  cd ..
   40  ls
   41  cd src/
   42  ls
   43  cd ..
   44  ls
   45  cd ..
   46  ls
   47  cd tmp/
   48  ls
   49  cd ..
   50  ls
   51  cd ..
   52  ls
   53  cd mnt/
   54  ls
   55  cd ..
   56  ls
   57  cd dev/
   58  ls
   59  cd ..
   60  ls
   61  cd opt/
   62  ls
   63  cd ..
   64  ls
   65  cd root/
   66  ls
   67  cd ..
   68  ls
   69  cd media/
   70  ls
   71  cd ,,
   72  ls
   73  cd ..ls
   74  cd ..
   75  ls
   76  cd lost+found/
   77  ls
   78  cd ..
   79  ls
   80  cd root/
   81  ls
   82  cd ..
   83  ls
   84  cd home/
   85  ls
   86  cd ..
   87  ls
   88  cd usr/
   89  ls
   90  cd include/
   91  ls
   92  cd ..
   93  ls
   94  cd src/
   95  ls
   96  cd ..
   97  ls
   98  cd ..
   99  ls
  100  cd lib
  101  ls
  102  cd ..
  103  ls
  104  cd usr/local/
  105  ls
  106  mysql -u root
  107  mysql -u root -p
  108  df -hT
  109  mount
  110  grep /home /etc/fstab
  111  fdisk -l
  112  cd /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_home
  113   dmesg | tail
  114  lsblk
  115  history
```

Comment: What does `grep /home /etc/fstab` output? Are you absolutely certain that /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_home was an ext4 partition? I understand it resembled one enough that fsck -t ext4 didn't refuse to operate on it, but that's not necessarily a guarantee that it was an ext4. Also, how did this get in this state? Did it just start happening one boot, was it a bad shutdown, a power spike (includes lightning strikes), a drink spill, earthquake, or something else?

Comment: @EdGrimm See my edit. brother.

Answer (score 1):

Have you recently migrated this partition to a new disk?  Or resized existing partition(s) on the same disk?  Looks to me like the the filesystem metadata isn't compatible with the underlying hardware, which would be consistent the hardware having changed for some reason (this is a perfectly legitimate thing to do - you just have to do it properly).

If you can afford to lose the data, I would simply `mkfs /dev/VolGroup/lv_home` and be done with it.

Better would have been to shrink the filesystem before moving to a new volume, and then expanding it to fit - if it's not too late, do this.

Otherwise, if you want to keep the data, first thing is to take an image of the partition in case it goes wrong:

```
dd if=/dev/VolGroup/lv_home of=/var/tmp/home.img bs=65534
```

Next run the fsck again, but when you get the `Interrupt?`, prompt say 'no' - you want to complete the fsck, not interrupt it.  When it runs to completion, run `fsck` again to be safe, and try to mount the drive then.  Let us know how that goes.

Comment: import data all in the /home, but now can not mount it. whether there is way to get the data of it?

Comment: I am very afraid to lose the /home data.

Comment: Use the dd command in the answer to create the image, then run fsck on it ('fsck /var/tmp/home.img'), then mount it ('mount /var/tmp/home.img /mnt').  All the contents of home should be visible under /mnt ('ls /mnt').  If it is, reformat your home partition ('mkfs /dev/VolGroup/lv_home'), mount it ('mount /dev/VolGroup/lv_home') and sync the contents from the image: ('rsync -a /mnt/ /home/').  Reboot and, if /home is working, you have successfully recovered and can now remove image.